# Prove that $V=W\bigoplus W^{\perp}$ for finite dimensional $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the full statement: if $V$ is finite dimensional vector space over the field $k$, and $W$ is a subspace of $V$, and if the bilinear form $\langle ,\rangle: X\times X\rightarrow k$ is nondegenerate with restricted domain on $W\times W$, that is, for each $x\in W$, if $\langle x,y\rangle=0$ $\forall y\in W$, then $x=0$.

Then $V=W\bigoplus W^{\perp}$.

My proof follows from the intuition of inner product:
$W\bigoplus W^{\perp}:=\{x+y\mid x\in W, y\in W^{\perp}\}$, it's obvious that both $W$ and $W^{\perp}$ are subspaces of $W\bigoplus W^{\perp}$. So let $B=\{e_1,...e_k\}$ be the orthonormal basis of $W$ and $W^{\perp}$.
Suppose for a contradiction, $V\neq W\bigoplus W^{\perp}$. The we can extend the basis $B$ to $B'=\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ which is the orthonormal basis of $V$, and there exists some $e_j\in B'\setminus B$.

So $\langle e_j, e_i\rangle=0$ for every $e_i$ in the basis of $W$, but then I'm not sure how to proceed. The proof would be complete if the bilinear form is nondegenerate on the whole space $V$, but this is clearly not assumed.

Comment: $W$ need not have an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w_1,\ldots,w_r$ be a basis of $W$. Consider the map
$\phi:V\to k^r$ given by $\phi(v)=(\left<w_1,v\right>),
\ldots,\left<w_r,v\right>$. Then (i) show $\phi$ is always nonzero on $W$,
(ii) $\ker\phi=W^\perp$, (iii) $W\cap W^\perp=\{0\}$ and (iv) $W+W^\perp=V$.

Comment: For (iv), which lemma did you use to show $dim(V)=dim(W)+(W^{\perp})$?